# Two POE devices on One Ethernet Cable via a Y splitter

Tags: ethernet, poe

Is it possible to run two PoE devices at the same time off of 1 ethernet cable from a PSE? Assuming that the ethernet cable is run through some sort of custom splitter  connector to both PoE Devices.

Comment: Will both use the ethernet cable for data? Is this "proper" PoE or just some proprietary pseudo-PoE PSE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POE specification does not allow for Y-splitters. Y-splitters do not follow the ethernet specifications either, and are a hack, it degrades your signal on the data lines.

If you used a Y-spliiter the PSE can't determine what class of load it has, and you also run the risk of overloading the rated current in the cable with two devices.

Don't use Y-splitters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't split the Ethernet cable as already answered. Ethernet is a point to point connection and does not support Y-connectors under any circumstance.

However it is perfectly legal (in spec) to power two or more devices from your PSE. The PSE reflects the output Class to the source quite correctly.
Things to note:

1. The ground for the PSE may not be the ground for the POE source (typically you may see a bridge rectifier on the POE receiver
2. It is more challenging to ensure overload protection for each of your endpoint devices.
3. Without per port over-current protections fault in one device may impact operation in the other. This may occur if you unplug/re-plug a device due to the input capacitor.